# Is undefined a partial list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

Is `undefined` a partial list in Haskell?

I know that `[1,2:undefined]` is partial but what about about `undefined` alone?

Comment: I'm not aware of a formal authoritative definition of "partial list", but usually, `undefined`, when used at a list type, is considered a partial list.

Comment: Could you please define what do you mean by _a partial list_?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`undefined` is a function that causes an error if you try to evaluate it. (However, if you don't try to evaluate it, it does no harm.) Let's examine the type signature for `undefined`:

```
ghci> :t undefined
undefined :: a
```

That `a` is a type variable, and since there are no constraints identified in the type signature (type constraints appear between `::` and `=>` symbols), `a` can be of *any* type.

I'm not sure if you really wanted a `:` in your example.

`[1,2,undefined]` is a list of integers, so the type of `undefined` in this expression is also an integer.

`(1:2:undefined)` is also a list of integers, but `:` takes a list as its second argument, so the type of `undefined` in this expression is a list of integer.

I don't think `[1,2:undefined]` makes sense. `1` is an integer, but `2:undefined` is a *list* of integers. You can't have a list with elements of different types.

---

EDIT:

`undefined` isn't *really* a partial list*, it's just a single value (which could be of any type, including a list). For example, `[1,2,undefined]` is a list with three elements. The first element is `1`, the second element is `2`, and the third element can't be evaluated -- but it is an integer.

*However, a list with `undefined` as the last element could be used to represent some sort of "partial list", insofar as you can't evaluate that element. (I think that's what @Daniel means). However, if there are elements before *or after* it, you could evaluate them. For example:

```
ghci> last [1,2,undefined,4]
4
```

---

EDIT #2:

Another example might help. Here I've created a list with four elements, one of which (`c`) is `undefined`. When I query ghci to find out the type of `c`, I see that it's just a single integer, not a list.

```
ghci> let (a:b:c:d) = [1,2,undefined,4]
ghci> :type c
c :: Integer
```

Comment: yea but undefined is a value of each type in haskell i am asking is a list undefined a partial list.

Comment: At `1:2:undefined`, the type of undefined is not `Integer` but `[Integer]` considering `1 :: Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear as the comments pointed out but let's make some assumptions. First you probably meant to write `1:2:undefined` as your example of a partial list.

```
> let p1 = 1:2:undefined
> :t p1
p1 :: [Integer]
```

So p1 has two elements and the rest is undefined which makes it a partial list in some sense. Following this definition this type-checks:

```
> let p2 = undefined :: [Int]
> :t p2
p2 :: [Int]
```

It has 0 elements and the rest is undefined. We can call it an empty partial list.

Another way to think about it is that `p1` is the same as `[1,2] ++ undefined` and `p2` is `[] ++ undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer for my question in Introduction to Functional Programing. *|* aka undefined is a Partial List (base of induction for them)